# select if there are more than n results but with conditions

Tags: sql-server

Unfortunately, similar question didn't include few "conditions" for this case.

So, my Table is:

```
| TimeId | Work_Role | User_Name |
----------------------------------
|    1   | users     | Oran      | *
|    2   | admin     | Ray       |
|    3   | users     | Oran      | *
|    4   | servs     | Amit      |
|    5   | admin     | Oran      |
|    6   | users     | Ray       |
|    7   | users     | Oran      | *
|    8   | servs     | Amit      |
|    9   | admin     | Oran      |
|   10   | users     | Oran      | *
```

I wish to display a list for user_name = "Oran" and Work_Role = "users" ONLY if there are more than 2 in the table.

In this case I expect to see:

```
| TimeId | Work_Role | User_Name |
----------------------------------
|    1   | users     | Oran      | 
|    3   | users     | Oran      | 
|    7   | users     | Oran      | 
|   10   | users     | Oran      |
```

I was trying to use HAVING according similar questions here, but it didn't provide any results. I assumed that maybe the multiple conditions have something to do with it.

So this is the "main" code:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE Work_Role = 'users' AND User_Name = 'Oran'
```

How do I add the condition to select only if there are more than 2 results?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SAMPLE DATA**

```
CREATE TABLE yourTable(
    TimeId      INT,
    Work_Role   VARCHAR(10),
    User_Name   VARCHAR(10)
)
INSERT INTO yourTable VALUES
(1, 'users', 'Oran'),
(2, 'admin', 'Ray'),
(3, 'users', 'Oran'),
(4, 'servs', 'Amit'),
(5, 'admin', 'Oran'),
(6, 'users', 'Ray'),
(7, 'users', 'Oran'),
(8, 'servs', 'Amit'),
(9, 'admin', 'Oran'),
(10, 'users', 'Oran');
```

## SOLUTION #1: USING CTE

```
WITH cte AS(
    SELECT *, cc = COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY Work_Role, User_Name) FROM yourTable
)
SELECT
    TimeId,
    Work_Role,
    User_Name
FROM cte
WHERE
    Work_Role = 'users' 
    AND User_Name = 'Oran'
    AND cc > 2
```

## SOLUTION #2: USING JOIN

```
SELECT
    t.*
FROM yourTable t
INNER JOIN(
    SELECT
        Work_Role,
        User_Name,
        cc = COUNT(*)
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY Work_Role, User_Name
)g
    ON t.Work_Role = g.Work_Role
    AND t.User_Name = g.User_Name
WHERE
    t.Work_Role = 'users' 
    AND t.User_Name = 'Oran'
    AND cc > 2
```

**CLEANUP SAMPLE DATA**

```
DROP TABLE yourTable
```

Answer (score 1):

just use this query its should work

```
SELECT UserName,Work_Role
   FROM yourtableName
   WHERE UserName='oran' AND Work_Role='users'
   GROUP BY UserName,Work_Role
   Having Count(Work_Role)>2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM   users u JOIN 
        (  SELECT user_name 
           FROM   users 
           GROUP BY user_name 
           HAVING count(user_name) > 2
        ) AS u2 ON u.user_name = u2.user_name
```

--

[example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ebe6e/3)